# I have stroed user authentication token in local storage but it's not working in SSR, Any solution?

Tags: node.js, angular8, server-side-rendering

I have created project in angular 8 and for authentication I have stored user token in local storage but due to the SSR it's not working properly. Any solution for this ?

I have check every route access as per user authentication token but due to the SSR it's not working.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if (localStorage.getItem("token") == null && this.token == null) {
            console.log("token")
            this.goToLogin();
            return true
        }
}
```

Every Time It's showing null in token

Comment: Please provide more information about the situation as well as specific code that doesn't work

Comment: @AbirTaheer Please check now

Comment: You can't access the authentication token when doing SSR unless it's part of the GET request that the browser makes. If your auth token is in localstorage, this won't work unless you set the auth token as a cookie so it's sent as a part of every request the browser makes.